# Why is there no web service project template for VS2010 targeting 4.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services

I'm trying to create a simple web Service in the 4.0 framework, but the project template is only available in 3.5? Have the MS team done this for a particular reason? Are they pushing us to WCF services?

Comment: Yes, they are. WCF is how MS wants people to write web services these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. WCF is replacing classic ASP.NET ASMX Web Services.